# R Correlation between factored variables

Tags: r, compare, correlation

I am wondering if there is an easy way to identify character/factor variables that are 100% correlated with another variable. So, in the example, the process would match 'color' and 'vehicle' as well as 'plant' and 'height'

```
color <- c('black', 'black', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow')
vehicle <- c('truck', 'truck', 'car', 'car', 'bike')
plant <- c('tree', 'flower', 'grass', 'tree', 'flower')
height <- c('tall', 'medium', 'short', 'tall', 'medium')

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(color, vehicle, plant, height))
```

Currently, I get the level number of the factors and run a correlation matrix and pull out the pairs that have a correlation of 1 (other than the self pairs).

The package compare works:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(compare)

f <- function(x) factor(x, levels= unique(x))

f.df <- as.tibble(df) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, f) %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.numeric) 

compare(f.df$color, f.df$vehicle)
compare(f.df$color, f.df$plant)
```

To get the correlations to test:

```
cor <- cor(f.df)

cor[lower.tri(cor)] <- 0

vars.corr <- data.frame(cor) %>%
  mutate(var1= rownames(.)) %>%
  select(var1, everything()) %>%
  gather(var2, val, -var1) %>%
  filter(var1!= var2) %>%
  filter(val > .99)
```

But I'm struggling with applying the compare function using map (purrr) to iterate over the pairs of variables (var1 and var2 in vars.corr), or writing a function and applying enquo properly to read in the variables from the list and apply to f.df.

But this seems like a rabbit hole now and I'm thinking surely there is an easier way!
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you considered using chi-squared as your test for a relationship?

Comment: I have considered chi-squared and I still get a high p-value if the factors in one variable are nested in the factors of another variable.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding levels = unique. It was my impression that levels = unique ordered the factors in the order they appear, which would appropriate for what I'm trying to do b/c when looking for exact correlation, the factors should appear in the same order respectively.

Comment: Nevermind, your `levels = unique` takes care of it.

Comment: Rather than correlation, I would suggest using `identical` to test pairs of the numeric versions. I think I've seen a question about doing that for all pairs of a list, I'll look for it.

Comment: oh great, I'll look around too. But please let me know if you find something. Thank you-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the individual pairs:

```
perfect_cor <-   function (var1, var2) {
  all(rowSums(as.matrix(table(df[[var1]], df[[var2]])) > 0) == 1)
}
perfect_cor <- Vectorize(perfect_cor) # necessary for using `outer`
```

To apply this over all pairs:

```
outer(names(df), names(df), perfect_cor)
```

Comment: This works very well for the example problem. For my real problem, I get a resulting matrix of all 'TRUE'. The function makes sense, and when I break down 'all(rowSums(as.matrix(table(df[[var1]], df[[var2]])) > 0) == 1)' and apply the column index of two non-correlated columns, it returns 'FALSE', as it should. So I'm not sure what I'm missing here......any ideas? It is a long matrix, 30 columns wide and ~15K rows but I don't see why that would matter.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you!