# Error in cor(data, use = "complete.obs", method = c("kendall")) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, correlation, stat

i need to do correlation between factor variable in r. i am using this command

```r
cor(data, use = "complete.obs", method =c("kendall"))
```

but I get

```r
Error in cor(data, use = "complete.obs", method = c("kendall")) : 'x' must be numeric.
```

any help would be highly appreciated. thanks

```r
structure(list(gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("f", "m"), class = "factor"), 
    age = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("adult", "child", "youngadult"
    ), class = "factor"), IMD = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Q1", "Q2", 
    "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"), class = "factor"), mutation = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("a", 
    "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Those are all factors, essentially discretized strings. How does one find *numeric* correlation among strings?

Comment: I suggest one or more from: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/108007/60634, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/102778/60634, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47078200/3358272